# Elapsed time display in foobar 2000

Tags: foobar2000

The elapsed and total time display in Foobar 2000 with the Metro skin ([download here](http://rikitiki11.deviantart.com/art/One-of-those-foobar-Metro-1-7-1-364177682#comments)) I use, is not aligned properly. I can't see the minutes track has played, which comes first. The time to the right of the track name is chopped. However on the seekbar it is ok.

[[image: picture]

<sup>Click for a full sized image</sup>](https://s14.postimg.org/elcp6rush/2013_11_03_182618.jpg)

There are scripts in the [ELPlaylist](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Components_0.9/ELplaylist_panel_%28foo_uie_elplaylist%29) settings window which I get when I right click on the playlist window. But unfortunately I don't know which parameter if any in the script should be changed to set a proper time format for the track duration, which would allow me to see the elapsed time.

Relevant ELplaylist code

- [Track list](https://gist.github.com/tripleowl/7293291)
- [Groupheader](https://gist.github.com/tripleowl/7293308)
- [Per second](https://gist.github.com/tripleowl/7293317)

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser.com. Your choice of words make it really hard to understand what your trying to explain. Could you rephrase your question? I think you have a much better chance of getting help if you do so.

Comment: Thank you Mogget! I apologize if my question didn't sound clear, but as a non-professional I find it difficult to explain differently. Could you please insert the snapshot of my Foobar playlist view after the first paragraph, that would explain the problem I have. Here's the address of it, with the annotation and the settings menu I get on right clicking the playlist, hope I can post the link here http://postimg.org/image/xqfygj9gd/

Comment: OK, I added the picture as you said. It will become visible when one of my peers has reviewed the change and approved it.

Comment: @tripleowl Copy&Paste all relevant code on [gist.github](https://gist.github.com/) and drop us the links. Have you tweaked that ELplaylist layout by yourself or is it a pre-configured one? If yes, show us the original download link. I can't figure out if your time display is on the status bar or in the ELplaylist. Whats that "metro skin"? More details please

Comment: Thank you Mogget!Hi nixda,there are skins for foobar player named Metro http://rikitiki11.deviantart.com/art/One-of-those-foobar-Metro-1-7-1-364177682#comments.   I'm not a programmer so I can only guess that the settings to be changed are under the Script tab ,on the first of the three tabs in that view. Here are the addresses for the scripts I uploaded on gist.github as you requested,for Track list, Group Header and Per second respectively, as shown on the snapshot: https://gist.github.com/tripleowl/7293291  https://gist.github.com/tripleowl/7293308  https://gist.github.com/tripleowl/7293317

Comment: Oh god, I need to find a single track which is longer than 1 hour to simulate your issue

Comment: Exactly nixda, hope I'm not inconveniencing you too much :) When I listen to audiobooks or other files longer than an hour in Now Playing mode the niftly coloured bolded elapsed time is a nice feature to have really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under ELplaylist settings, tab `Per Second`

Replace the last line

```
$font(,10,bold)$drawtextex(- %playback_time_remaining% | %length%,$sub(%el_width%,80),0,76,,%Track_Color_Playing%,right vcenter)
```

with this line, where I changed two values

```
$font(,10,bold)$drawtextex(- %playback_time_remaining% | %length%,$sub(%el_width%,124),0,120,,%Track_Color_Playing%,right vcenter)
```

[image]

Comment: Now it's perfect, thank you very much nixda! (**^1**, my vote up until I get enough reputation to hit the one beside your post :)